# Interpretation of the dialog between David and Weyland

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

*Alien: Covenant* (2017) starts with a dialog between David and Weyland. At some point David says this:

> You seek your creator I am looking at mine. I will serve you, yet you are human. You will die and I will not.

What was meant by it? It seems like a bunch of disconnected conclusions bunched up together with no obvious message, yet it was enough to rattle Weyland.

Answer (score 8):

**David was beginning to show his gross disregard for the role in which humanity placed him. And his gross disregard for humanity in general.**

Later in the movie,

> Walter told David that the David models had been discontinued precisely because each David's personality was so disturbing to humans.  We also learn that the Walter models had been created without the ability to initiate new ideas precisely because the David models had caused disruption as a result of initiating ideas like the idea in your quote in the OP.